# Angular - same view different binding contexts

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, knockout.js

Still trying to make a good transition into Angular so probably another newb-type question but please bear with me -

In Durandal/Knockout I can use the `compose` binding to show a view under the context of an object ie. -

```
<div data-bind="with: firstPerson">
    <!-- ko compose: 'views/person' --><!-- /ko -->
</div>
<div data-bind="with: secondPerson">
    <!-- ko compose: 'views/person' --><!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

to show the same view bound to two separate Knockout objects (observables)

But in Angular I have not found the correct way to bind everything within an element to a certain context.  How can I display multiple html files with various context(s?)?

I don't think this is the ng-repeat because it is not an array of objects, it is two separate properties on the same object ie -

1. ParentObject

   - FirstPerson
   - SecondPerson

**Edit**

Obviously with Durandal and Knockout I can use something like

```
<span data-bind="text: fullName"></span>
```

inside of the person view without having to define which parent it was a part of, how can this be achieved in Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ng-include](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude) to achieve that.

```
<ng-include ng-init="person=firstPerson"  ng-model="person" src="'/views/person.html'"/>
<ng-include ng-init="person=secondPerson" ng-model="person" src="'/views/person.html'"/>
```

`person.html` maybe look like

```
<div class="modal-body">
   {{person.firstName}}, {{person.lastName}}
</div>
```

So you can use the same model `person` to refer to different data model (`firstPerson` or `secondPerson`)